# How to flatten JSON values into frequency counts in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a column with JSON values like so:

```
{'A': 'true', 'B': 'false', 'C': 'true'}
{'A': 'true', 'C': 'false'}
{'D': 'true'}
{'C': 'true', 'A': 'false'}
```

I would like to create an SQL query which counts the number of entries with each key-value combination in the json.

Note that the keys and values are unknown in advance.

So the output of the above would be:

```
2   A=true
1   A=false
1   B=false
2   C=true
1   C=false
1   D=true
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a1||':'||a2, count(*) from (
  SELECT map_entries(cast(json_parse(x) as MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>)) row from 
    (VALUES ('{"A": "true", "B": "false", "C": "true"}'), ('{"A": "true", "C": "false"}'), ('{"D": "true"}'), ('{"C": "true", "A": "false"}')) as t(x)) 
    as nested_data CROSS JOIN UNNEST(row) as nested_data(a1, a2) 
group by 1;
```

```
 _col0  | _col1 
---------+-------
 D:true  |     1 
 B:false |     1 
 C:false |     1 
 C:true  |     2 
 A:false |     1 
 A:true  |     2
```

https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html